# Proving an eigenvalue bound without resorting to Weyl's law

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, sp.spectral-theory

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a smooth compact Riemannian manifold of dimension $n\geq 2$ with smooth boundary and denote by $\{\phi_k,\lambda_k\}_{k\in \mathbb N}$ its Dirihclet spectral decomposition for the Laplace-Beltrami operator $-\Delta_g$.

Is there a way to use somewhat elementary arguments to prove the convergence

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda_k^p} <\infty,$$

for sufficiently large $p$ depending on $n$, **without using the Weyl's law**?

Comment: If you count Sobolev embedding and elliptic regularity as "elementary", you can use these tools to show that $(1-\Delta_g)^{-s}$ has a continuous integral kernel for $s$ large enough ($s>n/2$ will suffice), and on taking traces one will obtain the claim.